# Redirect requests for old domain to specific page on new domain

Tags: iis, redirect

How can I forward requests for oldcompany.com to newcompany.com/oldcompany page?

We are in the process of transition whereby the olddomain.com content is now on our newcompany.com site with a specific URL.  I realise I will need to change the A record to point to our newcompany.com IP address but how do I forward traffic based on the original request to a specific page?

Once a re-direct is in place the oldcompany.com server will be taken down completely.

I was under the impression this could be done with host headers but can't seem to find anything relating to this scenario.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is creating a redirect HTML page on the old Server with a minimum timeout. Not that slick but all the work ie done by the client. Look for META REFRESH.

Comment: Sorry & thanks for replying but I should have mentioned the oldcompany.com server will be discontinued in the near future. [post updated to reflect]

Comment: Your DNS should have propagated by then, so that's fine.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding here but updating the A record will only point to the new server and so requests for oldcompany.com will go to newcompany.com rather than a specific page will it not?